# MySQL Cluster - Data Node Restarting when database corrupt

Tags: mysql, clustering, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I initially Have MySQL cluster with 2 Management and 2 Datanode. I added 2 Data node online and redistribute its data. So my current cluster setup is 4 Management Node + SQL and 4 Data node.

There is 3 Database inside that Cluster ( recently upgraded package to 7_5_9 ), lets call it :

Database_One
Database_Two
Database_Three

I need to dump sql data from each database. Database_One & Database_Two successfully exported. But when i want to dump Database_Three, all data node state suddenly change from Running to Starting..

Only when accessing Database_Three all data node status changed. I really have no clue what to do since the other two database working fine.

I've already tried to export data only from that database, but failed with error :

```
Warning  : Got temporary error 4028 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDB
Warning  : Got temporary error 4028 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDB
Warning  : Got temporary error 4028 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDB
Warning  : Got temporary error 4035 'Cluster temporary unavailable' from NDB
Warning  : Got temporary error 4035 'Cluster temporary unavailable' from NDB
Warning  : Got error 4009 'Cluster Failure' from NDB
Error    : Got error 4009 'Cluster Failure' from NDBCLUSTER
```

And after this, all data node status is Starting again.

I really need some enlightenment on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you hit a crash that caused the cluster to crash.
The cluster needs to be restarted and you can analyse the node logs
and cluster logs to see what could have caused the crash.

Comment: I've already restarted couple of times but still cannot access only from Database_Three..